# Convert `pid_t` into `char*` in Linux environment

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pid

I have a function called `writeToMemory(char*)` and all it does it writes the `char*` argument to the memory.

I want to write the current process ID to the memory.

I tried the following:

```
char newPID[30] = {0};
sprintf(newPID, "%d", (int) getpid());
```

but that leads to `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

What is the correct way to convert a `pid_t` type into a `char*`?

Comment: Use a debugger to find out *where* the program crashes, because that `sprintf` call should not crash. By the way, don't cast to `int`, use the proper format code instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg When I comment this line out everything is OK

Comment: The two lines you posted look fine. The error is probably elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Can you show more code? looks issue somewhere else.

Comment: @Jayesh Posted the whole code.

Comment: No no no, don't post *all* of your code! Build a debug version (add the `-g` flag when compiling) and run your program in a debugger. The debugger will stop when the crash happens, and let you examine and walk up the function call stack. If the crash is not in your code, walk up the stack until you are in your code, and examine the values of variables there. If you still can't figure it out *then* post a question to SO containing the relevant code and the values of all involved variables.

Comment: @Billie Where is sprintf in your whole code?

Comment: How is your sprintf related to the code you post? I do not see any sprintf in your whole program. So please post a minimal self containing program that shows the problem.

Comment: Oh, and don't use the value you do for signals. On Linux the signals you use are `SIGPIPE`, `SIGALRM` and `SIGTERM` (respectively). Those are system signals that may cause weird behavior if you use them in non-standard ways.

Comment: This may happen if you are returning `newPID` which a local variable from a function to some other function. To confirm this assumption, you can consider redefining newPID as static by `static char newPID[30] = {0}`

Comment: Show more code, typicall 10 lines before and 10 lines after the `sprintf.`

Comment: the couple of lines of code you posted work just fine, with no problems.  So those lines are not where the problem lies.  Post a minimal, cleanly compiles code that still shows the problem.  Otherwise we are guessing rather than being able to give definitive answers